# If I override UIAlertView (to show the progress bar, no dismiss), will it be rejected?

Tags: iphone, customization, uialertview

I just used UIAlertView to show "loading..." with a progress bar showing how much data my app is loading so far. And as the HIG says, I'm doubt Apple reviewers will approve that action. Since the alert is not supposed to "alert" users when things are going on normally.

So, if I override it with a custom background, would the Apple reviewers still reject it? My code is something like this:

```
@interface MyCustomAlert : UIAlertView {
    UILabel *alertTextLabel;
    UIImage *backgroundImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe they will.  I added a couple of text boxes and had no problem with multiple submissions.

Comment: what do you mean by adding text boxes. Where did you add them? (to the UIAlertView?)

Comment: Correct... I added them to the UIAlertView.  I wanted to build a prompt similar to the one used for entering the iTunes account on the phone.  It uses a UIAlertView with two textboxes allowing the user to enter their info.

Answer (score 1):

While it's probably not the most ideal solution, I also think they'll allow it. If they don't, you can cite their own iPhone commercial http://www.apple.com/iphone/gallery/ads/#office-large as having something nearly identical (if I'm understanding you correctly) in one of the feature applications (skip to 15 seconds into that "Office" iPhone commercial).

Comment: Perfect answer.  The "printing" uialertview in the commercial is, indeed, presenting what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think they will reject it for that, you can argue that the the dialog is used  to "alert" the person of the progress of what the app is doing. Only way youll find out for sure though is when you submit the app, i would recommend to have a backup plan just in case, but I think it will be ok.